# Installing 64bit ubuntu on Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5870 , possible?

Tags: cpu, architecture

I'm thinking if it's possible to use a 64bit ubuntu on a dual cpu architecture ?

How can i tell from /proc/cpuinfo ?

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5870  @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 13
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dts
bogomips    : 3991.23
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5870  @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 13
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dts
bogomips    : 3991.25
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: The manufacturer's specifications are the best way of finding out if the CPU is 32bit or 64bit. I have just looked up your CPU on the Intel web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Install 64 bit version of Ubuntu for Better Performance  [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T5870
(2M Cache, 2.00 GHz, 800 MHz FSB)](http://ark.intel.com/products/37034/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5870-%282M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29) (check this Intel Web)

because u got     Instruction Set   64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Multi-processor support does not depend on the word size (ie, 32- or 64-bit) of the Ubuntu install. You should be able to install either 32- or 64-bit Ubuntu on this machine, and have dual-core support work fine.

Answer (score 0):

almost all intel processors support 64 bit (lolzz). I have the same cpu and have installed 64 bit ubuntu 13.10. Works smooth as cheese. Don't worry, install the 64 bit version.