# Will Ubuntu 12.10 run on intel core 2 duo 2.00GHz?

Tags: 12.10, intel

I have a laptop with an Intel core 2 duo and i do believe it supports 64-bit OS. Will Ubuntu 12.10 64bit run on it without any trouble? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect it not to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It should run](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

The best thing to do is to make an Live USB /DVD of Ubuntu. The instructions are on the ubuntu.com website.

Boot your laptop from the USB or DVD and select the option "Try Ubuntu". This will allow you to test Ubuntu without installing it on your hard drive. You may want to check Ubuntu runs with your graphics card, sound card, wifi chip, web cam (if the laptop has it) etc. rather than just the CPU. Even though driver issues are less common than they used to be they crop up from time to time.

If something does not work out of the Live USB, it does not mean it won't work at all. It means you have to ask some questions and do some extra downloads and configurations yourself.

See [Installing 64bit ubuntu on Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5870 , possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83636/installing-64bit-ubuntu-on-intelr-coretm2-duo-cpu-t5870-possible) for some more information.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this site: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements 
There you find the minimum Requirements for Ubuntu.

I think it should run, it also runs on my Intel Core2Duo (2x 3.0GHz) machine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my notebook with an Intel Core Duo P8600 processor, that is just a little faster than yours. I think that there should be no problem installing on yours, according to the [Ubuntu 12.10 system requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements).
However, the best way to know if it runs fast on your PC or notebook is using [the Ubuntu Live DVD or USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) (for 12.10, all you need is one DVD or a capable USB pen drive).

Answer (score 0):

The laptop upon which I am writing this has an Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU 2.00GHz × 2 processor, same as yours, and Ubuntu runs great on it.  I have 4GB of RAM, and don't know how much you have, but since your processor appears to be the same as mine, I'd say that it won't limit your Ubuntu experience at all.